# Insert Into where not exists from specific category

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I have a table that contains several repair categories, and items that are associated with each repair category.  I am trying to insert all the standard items from a specific repair category that don't already exist into a Details table.

TblEstimateDetails is a join table for an Estimate Table and StandardItem Table.  And TblCategoryItems is a join table for the Repair Categories and their respective Standard Items.

For example in the attached image, Left side are all the Standard Items in a Repair Category, and Right side are all the Standard Items that are already in the EstimateDetails table.

[Standard Items All vs Already Included](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzrZ5.png)

I need to be able to insert the 6 missing GUIDS from the left, and into the table on the right, and only for a specific estimate GID.

This is being used in an Access VBA script, which I will translate into the appropriate code once I get the sql syntax correct.

Thank you!

```
INSERT INTO TblEstimateDetails(estimate_GID, standard_item_GID)
SELECT 
 '55DEEE29-7B79-4830-909C-E59E831F4297' AS estimate_GID
 , standard_item_GID 
FROM TblCategoryItems 
WHERE repair_category_GID = '32A8AE6D-A512-4868-8E1A-EF0357AB100E'
AND NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT standard_item_GID
  FROM TblEstimateDetails 
  WHERE estimate_GID = '55DEEE29-7B79-4830-909C-E59E831F4297');
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and he expected result. Make it easy to assists you, keep sample data simple - it's easy to see the difference between a and b, but not between 32A8AE6D-A512-4868-8E1A-EF0357AB100E and 32A8AE6D-A512-4868-8E1A-EF0357AB100E.

Comment: Changed the picture and added item descriptions to each GID to make it a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it figured out.  Access needs the subquery to be correlated to main query to work.  So I set the WHERE clause in the subquery to equal the matching column in the main query. And I had to join the Estimates table so that it picked only the items in a specific estimate.

```
SELECT 
 '06A2E0A9-9AE5-4073-A856-1CCE6D9C48BB' AS estimate_GID
 , CI.standard_item_GID 
FROM TblCategoryItems CI 
INNER JOIN TblEstimates E ON CI.repair_category_GID=E.repair_category_GID
WHERE E.repair_category_GID = '15238097-305E-4456-B86F-3787C9B8219B' 
AND NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT ED.standard_item_GID 
  FROM TblEstimateDetails ED 
  WHERE E.estimate_GID=ED.estimate_GID
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Some things to try: 1) simplify to a select query to see if it selects the right records, 2) use a NOT IN statement instead of NOT EXISTS. There's no reason NOT EXISTS shouldn't work, I'd just try a different way if it isn't working.

```
SELECT '55DEEE29-7B79-4830-909C-E59E831F4297' AS estimate_GID, 
standard_item_GID 
FROM TblCategoryItems 
WHERE repair_category_GID = '32A8AE6D-A512-4868-8E1A-EF0357AB100E'
AND standard_item_GID NOT IN 
(SELECT standard_item_GID FROM TblEstimateDetails 
WHERE estimate_GID = '55DEEE29-7B79-4830-909C-E59E831F4297');
```